How to automatically hide/unhide columns based on related month with VBA
I want create auto working monthly comparative charts as u know, to create a proper chart i have to hide unrealized months, for example i am working on Jan2June chart for now after June values are 0 but chart still shows after June months but it is not necessary.
I want to auto hide columns with VBA i have very simple code but it has some crash when i add more criteria. If i only define 6. month (June) the code works fine hides after June months. But ,if i add 7. month in code it works for July when i write 7 in to trigger cell but when i write 6 to trigger cell it only hide July and keeps other columns (months) unhide . Where is the bug ? Thanks in advance.
If Range("P1").Value = 6 Then  
Columns("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Columns("X:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
Columns("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
Columns("X:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  
If Range("P1").Value = 7 Then  
Columns("J:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Columns("Y:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
Columns("J:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
Columns("Y:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  
End Sub


If the value is 6, then the very last Else block is still True, i.e. Columns("J:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False and Columns("Y:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False still run, and undo the hiding you did in the first If block.

Without knowing exactly what the pattern is for hidden/shown columns, it's difficult to come up with a quick answer - but here is a an alternative method which is very flexible you could use:
Sub test()

    Dim all_columns As Range, p1_value As Long
    
    Set all_columns = Range("I:N,X:AC")
    columns_to_hide = Array("", "", "", "", "", "I:N,X:AC", "J:N,Y:AC", "K:N,Z:AC")
    p1_value = Range("P1").Value
    
    all_columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    
    If p1_value > 0 Then Range(columns_to_hide(p1_value - 1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub

The code hides all columns listed in the range all_columns, and then unhides those based on the value in P1, by looking up what range to unhide in the array. So it P1 has a value of 8, it will unhide the columns presented in the 8th array value.
The above caters for values up to 8, but you can just add more column ranges to the array for higher values.
